# PHPStorm: кодировка php-страницы - как заставить корректно читаться в utf-8?

Tags: php, .htaccess, кодировка, phpstorm, utf-8

Страница `http://yii2/frontend/web/index-test.php` содержит код:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "это index-test.php";
die;
```

и в браузере (хром, мозилла - на ubuntu) отображается со знаками вопроса вместо кириллицы.
Файл /var/www/yii2/frontend/web/.htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

#<FilesMatch "^.*\.(html|php)$">
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
#</FilesMatch>
```

Что нужно сделать для правильного отображения кодировки в браузере?
**P.S.** В комментарии получил совет сохранить файл в нужной кодировке. Поправил опции PHPStorm (Global Enkoding, Project Encoding), пересохранил файл - не помогло. Сохранил блокнотом - кодировка исправилась.
 **Кто знает как заставить PHPStorm сохранять в нужной кодировке сразу?**

Comment: сохранить **файл** index-test.php в кодировке utf-8?

Comment: @Ипатьев редактирую в phpstorm - Global Enkoding действительно был выставлен на Windows-1251, Project Encoding: <System default: UTF-8> . Изменил на UTF-8 обе опции, пересохранил файл. Ситуация осталась прежней.

Comment: Если ситуация осталась прежней, значит файл по-прежнему сохранен в 1251. Л - Логика.

Comment: @Ипатьев пересохранил блокнотом - помогло. спасибо