# Кодировка внутри SQL запроса PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Есть SQL-запрос, который включает в себя запрос на выборку и содержит `..where last_name like ?`. Когда подставляем в качестве значения латинские символы, запрос выполняется. Когда подставляем кириллицу, подготовленный запрос PDO содержит на месте ? квакозябры. Что можно сделать? Кодировка в базе и в объекте PDO выставлена utf-8.

Comment: откуда информация про "подготовленный запрос PDO содержит на месте ? квакозябры"?

Comment: но если это действительно так, то проблема скорее всего та же, что и в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1307719/179379)

Comment: да, это помогло, спасибо!